# issue when reading from txt to end of line

Tags: c++

I want to read from file and store it in variables/vectors but i have problem with passing only one line of txt to the vector. I found somewhere that getline is a good idea but it doesnt work for me in the way i am trying to do this. I want assign 1st,2nd and 4th line of txt to integer variables and 3rd and 5h line to vector arrays.

```
.txt:
1
4
-5 -1 0 8
7
7 9 2 0 -7 2 -5
```

output i want to get:

```
line1:1
line2:4
line3:-5 -1 0 8  
line4:7
line5:7 9 2 0 -7 2 -5
```

output i am getting:

```
line1:1
line2:4
line3: -5 -1 0 8 7 7 9 2 0 -7 2 -5
line4:6422000
line5:
```

code:

```
using namespace std;
void fromFile(std::fstream &myFile)
{
    int dataSets, size1, size2, value;
    std::vector<int> v1, v2;
    string line;
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        myFile >> dataSets;
        goToLine(myFile, 2);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < dataSets; ++i)
        {
            myFile >> size1;
            goToLine(myFile, 3);
            while (getline(myFile, line))
            {
                std::istringstream ss(line);

                while (ss >> value)
                {
                    v1.push_back(value);
                }
            }
            goToLine(myFile, 4);
            myFile >> size2;
            goToLine(myFile, 5);
             while (getline(myFile, line))
            {
                std::istringstream ss(line);

                while (ss >> value)
                {
                    v2.push_back(value);
                }
            }
            while (myFile >> value)
                v2.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    cout << "line1::" << dataSets << endl;
    cout << "line2::" << size1 << endl;
    cout << "line3: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
        cout << v1[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "line4:" << size2 << endl;
    cout << "line5: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++)
        cout << v2[i] << " ";
}

std::fstream &goToLine(std::fstream &file, unsigned int num)
{
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i)
    {
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to step through with a debugger, to see what values are being read at each instruction, and what is then being done.    Also, describing the output you WANT to get doesn't help, unless you describe what output you ARE getting.

Comment: @Peter i added information about output i am getting, can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could make it easier by creating a `struct` or `class` to keep the data. With that you can also add support for using stream operators to populate it.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// your data per entry in the file
struct data {
    std::vector<int> first{};
    std::vector<int> second{};
};

// read one data entry from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, data& d) {
    size_t tmp;
    if(is >> tmp) {          // read size of first vector
        d.first.resize(tmp); // set it to the correct size

        // copy <tmp> int:s from the stream into the vector
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), tmp, d.first.begin());

        if(is >> tmp) {           // read size of second vector
            d.second.resize(tmp); // set it to the correct size

            // copy <tmp> int:s from the stream into the vector
            std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), tmp, d.second.begin());
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// write one data entry to a stream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const data& d) {
    os << d.first.size() << '\n';
    if(auto it = d.first.begin(); it != d.first.end()) {
        os << *it;
        for(++it; it != d.first.end(); ++it) {
            os << ' ' << *it;
        }
    }
    os << '\n';

    os << d.second.size() << '\n';
    if(auto it = d.second.begin(); it != d.second.end()) {
        os << *it;
        for(++it; it != d.second.end(); ++it) {
            os << ' ' << *it;
        }
    }
    os << '\n';

    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<data> datas;

    size_t number_of_datas;

    if(std::ifstream file("filename"); file && file >> number_of_datas) {
        // copy <number_of_datas> datas from file into the empty vector
        // using std::back_inserter
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<data>(file), number_of_datas,
                    std::back_inserter(datas));
    }

    // output
    std::cout << datas.size() << '\n';
    for(auto& d : datas) {
        std::cout << d;
    }
}
```

The two `vector`'s could be combined into just one `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` but I kept them separate to make it easier to illustrate.